# What can I do to get the most "fully stocked" tower bux bonuses?

Tags: tiny-tower

I'm interested in any answer, but I'm particularly curious if there is a limit on how often you can it for a given store.   For the Food store's it is normally hard to keep them stocked, and if I can only get "Fully Stocked" tower bux bonus say once an hour per store, than I wouldn't work as hard to keep those stores full.

Comment: I am interested in the answer to this too, I noticed sometimes when I fully stock them I don't get the bonus. I am sure there is a limitation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You *always* get the bonus, the issue you're noticing is you don't always get the  *Tower Bux*. You'll note a little (useless) coin bonus at the bottom right every time you fully stock. They actually used to have the same Fully Stocked notification for Coin Bonuses, but it was annoying as heck and [they removed it long ago](http://tinytowerwiki.com/Tiny_Tower_%28game%29#Version_1.2.1).

The Tiny Tower wiki claims you have a [1/6 chance of getting Bux](http://tinytowerwiki.com/Tower_Bux#Tower_Bux) for fully stocking a store.

Quickly stocked floors like Food floors are easy to fully stock if you're paying constant attention and they'll thus get you the most fully stocked bonuses. Otherwise, just stock stores which you can keep up with at a reasonable place. Quickly stocked floors are hard to keep up with, and it's probably not worth changing your playing style, you'll have to pay a LOT of attention to the game to keep up with <1 hour restock times.

Generally, just don't change your style of play other than always stocking your third items first. Also, Dream Job Bitizens double stock but not stock time or sales, so your stock lasts longer; this means you have 2x as much time to get the fully stocked bonus.

Comment: The wiki claims that (IIRC, can't check right now) there's a 1/16 chance of getting the tower buck fully stocked bonus, which is not that bad.

Comment: @Tacroy thanks for the tip, turns out it's 1/6 as Emerica's post suggested

Comment: That's right, now I remember - 1/16th is the chance of getting a tower buck as an elevator tip.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer.  I updated the question to be a little more specific.  You were right that it was the random tower bux bonus I was after.

Comment: @EBongo I figured; no one cares about the coin bonus, just like with the elevator tips :)

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you always get a fully stocked gold bonus, but getting the fully stocked bonus bux is totally random. Much like getting a tip from the elevator.

[This](http://www.gamespot.com/tiny-tower/forum/bonus-bux-for-fully-restocking-60396900/) thread shows that it is about a 1 in 6 chance to get bux for fully stocking.

Comment: +1 for math.  I gave the check to Ben Brocka for the most complete answer, but you definitely added valuable insight.

Answer (score 1):

To keep the food stores (in your example) longer, there are only two things you can do.

**Spend Tower Bucks** to (3 per upgrade) to upgrade the stock level of all three levels.  This will increase your stock by 75 items on all 3 levels.

**Make your TinyTower citizens happy** by placing them in their dream job.  That will double the total stock per how many dream job employees you have at that store.  Note: This is random when you gain the residents (don't be afraid to evict them!).

Both of these paths can significantly increase your chances for receiving the bonus.  [ But from my experience it seems to be random ]

Comment: Just to clarify about your dream job comment: Placing 1, 2 or 3 bitizens in their dream job will multiply x2 the stock produced for the 1st 2nd and 3rd item respectively, so having one bitizen in his dream job will multiply the 1st item, placing 2 will multiply the 1st and 2nd and placing all three will multiply all item.

Comment: Note that the more stock a store has, the longer it takes for any one stock level to empty so that you can re-fill it.  This means that it takes longer for an attempt at getting the Fully Stocked bonus TB.

Comment: Foxtrot - I may have caused confusion by not being specific enough.  I have since clarified in the question and title that I'm trying to figure out how to maximize the Fully Stocked tower bux bonus.